# angularjs filter does not allow <video> playback

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, video

In this fiddle  :http://jsfiddle.net/yncwgu53/40/ I'm displaying multiple videos using the video tag with an angularjs filter. The problem is that when I filter for an item that does not exist and then filter an item that does exist the window is blacked out and the video controls are not avilable. e.g filter for 'zz' then backspace twice clearing filter dialog in fiddle. Why is this occurring and how to display the video as part of filtering ?

fiddle src :

```
  <body ng-app="myApp">

  <div style="margin-bottom:20px">

    <input type="text" ng-model="search">
    </div>

      <div ng-controller="myCtrl">

   <div style="margin-bottom:20px" ng-repeat="item in items">

<video id="{{item.id}}" 
  class="video-js vjs-default-skin" 
  controls
  preload="auto" 
  width="320"
  height="264"
  data-setup='{"techOrder":["youtube"], "src":"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xYemnKEKx0c"}'></video>

                </div>

</div>

</body>


var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope , $filter) {

    $scope.items = [
        {id:1, name:'John'},
        {id:2, name:'Steve'},
        {id:3, name:'Joey'},
        {id:4, name:'Mary'},
        {id:5, name:'Marylin'}];

    $scope.items2 = $scope.items;

    $scope.$watch('search', function(val)
    { 
        $scope.items = $filter('filter')($scope.items2, val);
    });

});
```

Update

added src attribute :

```
<video id="{{item.id}}" 
  src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xYemnKEKx0c"
```

Updated fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/yncwgu53/43/ but same result.

Comment: the black videos have no `src` attrib; hard-code it if it's not dynamic

Comment: @dandavis updated with src but same result, please see question update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used iframe instead , updated fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/yncwgu53/55/

src :

```
  <body ng-app="myApp">



  <div style="margin-bottom:20px">

    <input type="text" ng-model="search">
    </div>

      <div ng-controller="myCtrl">

   <div style="margin-bottom:20px" ng-repeat="item in items">

  <iframe id="{{item.id}}"  type="text/html" 
    width="240" 
    height="185" 
    src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/xYemnKEKx0c"
    frameborder="0">
</iframe>

                </div>

</div>

</body>




var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope , $filter) {

    $scope.items = [
        {id:1, name:'John'},
        {id:2, name:'Steve'},
        {id:3, name:'Joey'},
        {id:4, name:'Mary'},
        {id:5, name:'Marylin'}];

    $scope.items2 = $scope.items;

    $scope.$watch('search', function(val)
    { 
        $scope.items = $filter('filter')($scope.items2, val);
    });

});
```